# Android studio CMake fails on linking library

Tags: android, c++, c, cmake, android-ndk

I have android studio Native C++ project which has `native-lib.c` file. Inside it I am using other static C++ library. The Library is linked Ok but I got error on `Linking C shared library C:\user....\libnative-lib.so`

There are a lot of errors which some of them are:

```
 error: undefined reference to 'operator new(unsigned int)' 
 
 error: undefined reference to 'operator delete(void*)' 
 
 error: undefined reference to '__cxa_end_catch' 
 
 error: undefined reference to '__dynamic_cast' 
 
 ...ndk/21.1.6352462/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/lib/gcc/i686-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../i686-linux-android/bin\ld:
 the vtable symbol may be undefined because the class is missing its key function
```

I am building only for abi x86 I have this in my gradle:

```
ndk {
     abiFilters "x86"
}
```

And I have checked my other library is built for x86 abi too. Any help why this might happen?

I found this: ***GNU's libstdc++ is no longer included in NDK r18. You need to use libc++.***
and I am using ndk 21. But I don't know why it gives me error when I have not specified to use `libstdc++`. I have this includes in my `native-lib.c`:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <malloc.h
```

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:
`CMakeLIsts.txt`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10.2)

add_library( native-lib SHARED
             native-lib.c )

find_library( log-lib
              log )

add_library(MyLib STATIC IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(MyLib  PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libMyLib.a)

target_link_libraries( native-lib
                       android
                       ${log-lib} )
```

And for building MyLib.a I used Qt to build static library. I used Qt static 5.14.2 version and for compilers in the kit there are selected Android Clang C and Android Clang C++ from NDK 21.1.635.

Comment: Show us your CMakeLists.txt and tell us how your existing static library was compiled. Did you use the same compiler you're trying to use now?

Comment: thank you for comment I updated my question

Comment: native-lib only contains a C file, so it is linked as a C library. Change the extension to .cpp. You should probably also link your native-lib with MyLib somewhere.

Comment: I have just found solution with copying `libc++_shared.so` from the ndk,  placing next to MyLib.a  and linkin it the same way like my library. There are no errors now. But i don't know why was this needed. Thank you anyway for your time @Botje